# Save each layer as individual file with ifel in terra

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a large raster stack composed of dozens of layers. I would like to save each layer directly to disk with `ifel` however the `filename` function within `ifel` creates a single output file. The help file for `ifel` directs towards `writeRaster` for additional arguments but in `writeRaster`, each layer is saved individually which is what I would like.

```
r <- rast(nrows=5, ncols=5, xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1)
values(r) <- c(-10:0, NA, NA, NA, 0:10)

s<-r*1.2

r.stack<-c(r, s)
names(r.stack)<-c("r", "s")
t <- rast(nrows=5, ncols=5, xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1)

values(t) <- c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5))

x <- ifel(t==3, 5, r.stack,
          filename=paste("test",names(r.stack), ".tiff", sep=""))
#Warning message:
#[cover] only the first filename supplied is used
```

**output**: a single .tiff file with both layers

**desired output**: two .tiff files for each layer named with the layer name

```
writeRaster(x,filename=paste("test",names(r.stack), ".tiff", sep=""))
```